# EF "Code First" and Object/Relational Impedance

Tags: object-oriented-design, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to learn more about the current orthodoxy with respect to ASP.NET MVC application design, and I stumbled upon something that confuses me, relating to the choice among database design strategy (code first, model first...). This is the author's claim (paraphrasing somewhat):

> The code first approach does not allow you to apply inheritance. The
>   code first approach permits you to define the model from the code, but
>   will not create classes. The code first approach uses the POCOs (Plain
>   old CLR objects) model to create classes. If your application must be
>   able to apply inheritance and/or create classes, don't use code first.
>
> The database first approach supports the ability to incorporate
>   inheritance hierarchies and the creation of classes. Similarly, with
>   the model first approach you will produce Entities, relationships, and
>   inheritance hierarchies right on the design surface of framework.

Right away, this line of discussion strikes me as odd. My feeling is that object-relational impedance is going to be an issue regardless of code first / model first. I fail to see how selecting, say, model first offers any advantage in dealing with O-R impedance. Is there really some sort of way to create inheritance relationships in that graphical EDMX editor Microsoft supplies with Visual Studio? I didn't think there was, but, then again, I have absolutely no desire to muddle my work in that designer (which, to me, resembles an Entity-Relationship diagram, *not* some sort of OOD diagram).

Similarly, I find the assertion that "[t]he database first approach supports the ability to incorporate inheritance hierarchies and the creation of classes" perplexing. This approach presumably involves constructing the database in SQL Server Management Studio, and I'm not aware of any OOD type features in that tool. (Again, I must admit that I have never wanted to find them if they do exist...)

So, I'm left with the overall belief that whatever approach is chosen, the developer will end up having to manually create some set of wrapper classes exhibiting an inheritance hierarchy (assuming that he wants one), and generally to deal with O-R impedance. What is the real disadvantage of code first here?

After I typed this all out, it occurred to me that all of that quoted text above may be saying that POCOs have to use simple types (**int**, **bool**, and the like). Is that really what's being pointed out here? If so, how do other approaches to database design get around this?

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the author's comments, either a book title and page number or a web link?

Comment: Also, [this blog series by Tom Dykstra](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) seems especially relevant.

Comment: Robert, Tom Dykstra is showing an example where he uses code first and then builds an inheritance hierarchy... again, I'm compelled to ask "why not use Code First with inheritance"? I probably should read through that whole blog, though. It does look highly relevant. The long quote I posted paraphrases something I saw while taking an interactive certification practice test. I actually had to re-type what I remembered seeing from memory, and I don't have an author, ISBN, etc.

Comment: Well, first of all, "Code First" is a bit of a misnomer.  It has always been possible to generate classes from tables, even in "code first."  Secondly, inheritance hierarchies are not generally well-supported in relational databases, which is all this may amount to.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I've used a hybrid code first / update-from-database approach before, with good results. And none of these approaches really support OOD in a neat, transparent way. But what confused me is this claim that somehow you'd want to choose model first or database first if you wanted to build an object hierarchy. In fact, I got the question wrong because I didn't choose "code first" as the strategy to avoid when doing inheritance. I don't get it. Maybe I just bought the world's worst exam prep tool.

Comment: @user1172763, about *that quoted text above may be saying that POCOs have to use simple types*: you can have POCOs that have other POCOs.